# Django Run a Test By Its Filename

Tags: python, django

I have a django application with a test called `test_thing.py`

Ive been running my test as such: `python3 manage.py test --pattern="test_thing.py"`

Is there a way that I can run the test by its filename?

I tried `python3 manage.py test apiv2/tests/test_thing.py` but I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

But when I run with the `--pattern` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`python manage.py test apiv2.tests.test_thing`.